# Show DIV > SPAN only when DIV > TABLE >TR is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a layout that looks like this

```
<div class="categoery">
    <span>categorie title</span>
    <table>
        <tr class="item show">....</tr>
        <tr class="item show">....</tr>
        <tr class="item none">....</tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="categoery">
    <span>categorie title</span>
    <table>
        <tr class="item none">....</tr>
        <tr class="item none">....</tr>
        <tr class="item none">....</tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

​

Now what I want to the is the following. The first div will be the category title, and the two rows.

Now in the second div, I want the whole div completely hidden.

CSS has no parent seelctor like: `div < tr.none{ display:none; }`.

I asume another thing I can use is the hasClass from jQuery, but I was wondering if there is a pure CSS approuch.

==

Maybe something like setting the div to height:0, but block elements(tr) with a top margin will force the div to expand??

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$('.categoery').each(function(k,v) {
    if($(this).children('table').find("tr").css("display")=='none') {
    // alternate
  //if($(this).children('table').find("tr").hasClass("none")) {
        $(this).children('span').hide();
    }
});
```

I even created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/zwwhV/). I hope this was what was asked for.

Comment: Yes this is kind of the code that I use right now. But I am working with large datasets and this code (each/find) just takes a lot of processing. I was looking for a top-level css solution that does not have to loop trough the whole dataset everytime. Should have added that to the question. But thanks for the code, I will use it if there is absolutely no better code.

Comment: @SaifBechan if that's the case, cache the results of the find

Comment: @SaifBechan  put some logic in dataset loops to add classes to containers as well as rows

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr.none').closest('.categoery').css('display','none');`

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what the hide/show rules are. Following will hide categories and only show ones that have a TR with class "show" in them

```
 $('.categories').hide().filter(':has(tr.show)').show()
```

Can remove the hide() by using css but again, rules not very clear